# Spring mvc tiles configuration

Tags: spring

how to add spring tiles configuration feature through xml?...for example
suppose If I've 1000+ tiles resolver xml files.how can I add those xml files ? I need to add all the xml files or is there any new feature to inject all files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to configure each view definition file. `TilesConfigurer` `definitions` property support wildcard characters.

In the following example `TilesConfigurer` will try to load all `views.xml` under any subpath of  `/WEB-INF/views/`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" id="tilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml</value>
            <!-- Scan views directory for Tiles configurations -->
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Hope this helps!